# Jmeter passes me to application with wrong credentials

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter

i recorded script with valid credentials. Now i am trying to login the application with wrong credentials to test if application is responding correctly.
Unfortunately it passes me with nonsense credentials and makes changes inside the application. But if i try to login the application through the web browser the login process fails as expected.

I am using parameters in csv file and hardly posted data.

Any idea how to fix it please?

Michal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite possible to say what's wrong without seeing your

- [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) settings
- [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) settings
- Request details in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener

It might be the case that you're sending some [header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) which is being used for authentication instead of credentials.

Another possibility is that you're not actually logged in, JMeter just reports [HTTP Status Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) < 400 as successful so it might worth adding a [Response Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/response-assertions-in-jmeter-32-new-and-improved) which will be explicitly checking whether user is logged in or not.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your response.

At the last test i used "User Defined Variables" where i defined parameters "login" and "pwd". Both are keeping same value "GoodMorning".
Tree seems like this:

001_ login page - passed
002_ login submit - passed
003_ webhomepage - passed
etc.

Comment: Submit request:

POST https://somewebpage.eu/admin/login

POST data:
e_mail=GoodMorning&password=GoodMorning&_submit=Prihl%C3%A1si%C5%A5&_do=loginForm-submit

Cookie Data:
PHPSESSID=tkggnj1ak0ehg0giqv73fhrpcb

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: https://somewebpage.eu
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SmartMeter.ioRecorder/1.2.15 Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Electron/1.8.2 Safari/537.36
Referer: https://somewebpage.eu/admin/login

Comment: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 88
Host: somewebpage.eu

Comment: How do you pass `e_mail` and `password` parameters in `login submit` request and where `PHPSESSID` cookie comes from?

Comment: I tried the method with Respont Assertion and reconfigured my CSVs. Now it seems that shows results what i want to see. Thank you very much for your time and informations. :)